# Extract day of week from database field in PostgreSQL

Tags: datetime, postgresql-9.1

I simply want to show a date and its day of the week from a table.

The following works:

```
select "invDate", (select extract (dow from timestamp '2014-09-22'))
from "tblInvMaster"
```

But the moment I try to use the actual field like the example below, it doesn't work:

```
select "invDate", (select extract (dow from timestamp "invDate"))
from "tblInvMaster"
```

The above gives a syntax error where the field name starts in timestamp.

What is the correct method of getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax

```
TYPENAME 'VALUE'
```

e.g.

```
TIMESTAMP '2014-01-01'
```

is only valid in SQL for type literals.

If you want to *cast* a non-literal value you must use an explicit cast. Most likely you don't require a cast at all, and can just write:

```
extract(dow from "invDate")
```

as `"invDate"` should already be a timestamp or date. If it isn't, you'll need to `CAST("invDate" AS timestamp)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using TIMESTAMP to cast it thinking that my field was only a DATE and NOT DATETIME. But then like you said it wasn't necessary. I also found in the docs online that a DATE is automatically cast as TIMESTAMP. So there was no need for casting.